# Background image will not appear in react audio player

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am attempting to add a SoundCloud audio player to my website. I am using the react-soundplayer, and I am able to get the music properly from SoundCloud but the styling/background image of the player will not appear.

I've tried using different images to see if the image was the problem, however, it wasn't. I also tried creating the player as a separate component in a different file and then importing it to my index, sadly this also was unsuccessful.

```
const Player = withSoundCloudAudio(props => {
    let { track, duration, currentTime } = props;

    return (
    <div className="py2 white bg-cover bg-top rounded relative" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${GODbg})`}}>
        <div className="bg-black absolute top-0 right-0 left-0 bottom-0 muted" />
            <div className="center py4 relative z1">
                <h3 className="h4 nowrap caps mb0">{track ? track.user.username : ''}</h3>
                <h2 className="h0 nowrap caps m0">{track ? track.title : ''}</h2>
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-center px2 relative z1">
                <PlayButton
                className="flex-none h2 mr2 button button-transparent button-grow rounded"
                {...props} />
                <VolumeControl
                className='mr2 flex flex-center'
                buttonClassName="flex-none h2 button button-transparent button-grow rounded"
                rangeClassName="custom-track-bg"
                {...props} />
                <Progress
                className="flex-auto bg-darken-3 rounded"
                innerClassName="rounded-left bg-white"
                value={(currentTime / duration) * 100 || 0}
                {...props} />
        </div>
    </div>
    )
});
```

It should look like the BackgroundSoundPlayer.js example on [this](http://labs.voronianski.com/react-soundplayer/) page, but it does not.